# Obtain the number of CPU cores in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, cpu-cores

I want to obtain the number of cores available in Julia. Currently I am doing the following:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport psutil
nCores = psutil.cpu_count()
```

This calls a Python function. I would like, however, to use some Julia procedure. How can it be done?

Comment: The constant [Base.CPU_CORES](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/constants/#Base.CPU_CORES) may do the trick (but it counts hyper-threading cores as full-cores).

Comment: `psutil.cpu_count()` reports 8 cores on my Intel i7-2720QM-powered laptop so it also counts hyper-threading cores as full cores.

Comment: This question needs a new answer. All the current answers are deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain about this, but `CPU_CORES` returns the number of (hyper-threading) cores on my machine (OSX 10.9.5 and Julia 0.3.5), even when I start Julia in serial mode. I've been checking the number of available cores using `nworkers()` and `nprocs()`. Starting up Julia without the `-p` flag this returns 1 for both.

When I start julia as `julia -p 4`

```
julia> nprocs()
5

julia> nworkers()
4
```

In both cases `CPU_CORES` returns 8.

Comment: ```Base.CPU_CORES``` is deprecated. In order to obtain this information, you should try ```Sys.CPU_CORES```. More details could be found [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/9ab1519db4ab8c525f84fce542bfc463d9a2b071/base/sysinfo.jl#L21)

Comment: For logical cores `Sys.CPU_CORES`, and for physical cores you can use CpuId.jl or Hwloc.jl

Answer (score 15):

`Sys.CPU_CORES` is not defined in Julia v1.1.0. However, the following does the job.

```
length(Sys.cpu_info())
```

Comment: It will bring the number of logical cores and not physical cores.

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of Julia, you can use `Sys.CPU_CORES` (and not `Base.CPU_CORES` as some answers mentioned). Tested on 0.6.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/environment-variables/#JULIA_NUM_THREADS), the "number of cores available" can be limited by the `JULIA_NUM_THREADS` environment variable.

To see the number of threads available to Julia, use

```
Threads.nthreads()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Sys.CPU_CORES` is undefined in Julia 1.0.0 (at least, running on a macbook—I don't imagine that would make a difference). Instead, use `Sys.CPU_THREADS`.

Comment: Note, however, that cpu threads != cores, in particular for modern intel cpus with hyper threading.

Comment: But I think the old `Sys.CPU_CORES` did count HT as cores as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Julia but "psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)" in Python gives you the number of physical CPUs (hyper threaded ones are not counted).

Answer (score 0):

In Julia 1.10, you can do

```
length(Sys.cpu_info())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hwloc is a useful package for this purpose.

```
using Hwloc
num_physical_cores()
num_virtual_cores()
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over previous answers? What benefits does it provide that they don’t offer?

Comment: Because, assuming that Hwloc is well implemented, it gives you directly the number of physical and virtual cores.